# Jest - mocking a default export module

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have a module which export a default.

```
import { createNamespace } from 'node-request-context';
const namespace = createNamespace('request-metadata');

export default namespace;
```

This module is required in a different file, like so:

```
....
import loggingContext from '../utils/loggingContext';
....

export function myFunc(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ......
    loggingContext.run(() => {
      loggingContext.set('metadata', {
         userId
      });
    });
    const userEmail = loggingContext.get('metadata', 'email');
  });
}

...
```

So we can see that the `loggingContext` module exports `run`, `get` and `set` methods.
I want to mock it and those methods in my unit tests but I keep getting an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'metadata' of undefined`

This is my latest attempt to mock it

```
import loggingContext from '../../src/utils/loggingContext';

jest.mock('../../src/utils/loggingContext', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: {
      run: jest.fn(),
      get: jest.fn(),
      set: jest.fn(),
    }
   };
});
```

Please advise how can I mock it properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mock it like this way
First import your default export module

```
const loggingContext = require('../../src/utils/loggingContext');
```

Then mock this module using jest.mock()

```
jest.mock('../../src/utils/loggingContext');
```

Now you can write your expected mock implementation for this module like below

```
const mockObject = {
  run: jest.fn(),
  get: jest.fn(),
  set: jest.fn(),
}
loggingContext.mockImplementationOnce(() => mockObject);
```

Comment: Getting this error `loggingContext_1.default.mockImplementationOnce is not a function`

Comment: Can you please share the code of your test file, so that I can understand what are you trying to do with code. I tried to create a similar scenario at my local machine without any assertion in test and that was working for me.
test file
import loggingContext from './loggingContext'
import { myFunc } from './paractice'

jest.mock('./loggingContext', () => {
    return {
      __esModule: true,
      default: {
        run: jest.fn(),
        get: jest.fn(),
        set: jest.fn(),
      }
     };
});

it('sample test', ( ) => {
    myFunc()
    console.log("Inside test")
})